# How do I construct and plot functions properly using NestList?

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, function-construction, iteration

I am trying to construct a function using `NestList` and plot the values. Although the individually used and defined functions in my notebook seem to do the right thing (have compared the outputs with an equivalent Python notebook), I am failing at the procedure. In particular, the performance is very poor, but this must be due to my implementation.

***Background:*** The idea is to investigate error propagation function of qubit rotations (using $SU2$ rotations). Using Mathematica, I plan to use CAS features like simplifications or determining curve equations. The following plot shows the angular error after $n$ rotations of a qubit on the bloch sphere:

[image]

The corresponding Python Code looks as follows:

```
rot_x = pi/100
rot_y = pi/100
rot_z = pi/100
num_iterations = 200

start_vec = [1, 0, 0]
err = 0.2

x = np.arange(0, num_iterations, 1, dtype=int)
ϕ_error_propagation_vec = np.zeros(shape=(num_iterations))
θ_error_propagation_vec = np.zeros(shape=(num_iterations))

vec = start_vec
vec_err = qubitmatrix_to_cartesian(rn_su2_euler(start_vec, 0, err, 0))

for i in range(num_iterations):    
    polar = cartesian_to_spherical(vec)
    polar_err = cartesian_to_spherical(vec_err)
    (ϕ_rotated, θ_rotated) = (polar[1], polar[2])
    (ϕ_rotated_err, θ_rotated_err) = (polar_err[1], polar_err[2])

    θ_error_propagation_vec[i] = θ_rotated_err - θ_rotated
    ϕ_error_propagation_vec[i] = ϕ_rotated_err - ϕ_rotated

    M_q_rotated = rn_su2_euler(vec, rot_x, rot_y, rot_z)
    M_q_rotated_err = rn_su2_euler(vec_err, rot_x, rot_y, rot_z)
    vec = qubitmatrix_to_cartesian(M_q_rotated)
    vec_err = qubitmatrix_to_cartesian(M_q_rotated_err)

plt.plot(x, ϕ_error_propagation_vec, θ_error_propagation_vec)
plt.show()
```

For the sake of completeness, I provided the whole working Notebook including all functions [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Sultanow/quantum/blob/main/bloch_sphere/rotate_su2_qiskit_eldar-sultanow.ipynb).

***My question and approach:*** I reimplemented this script using Mathematica (v.13) as follows:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
qubitmatrixToCartesian[Mq_] := (
   q1 = Re[(Mq[[1, 2]] + Mq[[2, 1]])/2];
   q2 = Re[(Mq[[2, 1]] - Mq[[1, 2]])/(2*I)];
   q3 = Re[Mq[[1, 1]]];
   Return[{q1, q2, q3}];
   );
rnSU2euler[vec_, rx_, ry_, rz_] := (
   sphericalVec = ToSphericalCoordinates[vec];
   \[Theta] = sphericalVec[[2]];
   \[Phi] = sphericalVec[[3]];
   sx = PauliMatrix[1];
   sy = PauliMatrix[2];
   sz = PauliMatrix[3];
   Mq = Sin[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Phi]]*sx + Sin[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Phi]]*sy + 
     Cos[\[Theta]]*sz;
   Un = {{Exp[-I*(rx + rz)/2]*Cos[ry/2], -Exp[-I*(rx - rz)/2]*
       Sin[ry/2]}, {Exp[I*(rx - rz)/2]*Sin[ry/2], 
      Exp[I*(rx + rz)/2]*Cos[ry/2]}};
   Return [Un . Mq . ConjugateTranspose[Un]];
   );
rotateVector[vec_, rx_, ry_, rz_] := (
   MqRotated = rnSU2euler[vec, rx, ry, rz];
   Return[qubitmatrixToCartesian[MqRotated]];
   );
errorPropagation[n_, vec_, vecError_, rx_, ry_, rz_] := (
   v = N[NestList[rotateVector[#, rx, ry, rz] &, vec, n]];
   vErr = N[NestList[rotateVector[#, rx, ry, rz] &, vecError, n]];
   polar = Map[ToSphericalCoordinates, v];
   polarErr = Map[ToSphericalCoordinates, vErr];
   Return[MapThread[Subtract, {polar[[All, 2]], polarErr[[All, 2]]}]];
   );
ListPlot[errorPropagation[4, {1, 0, 0}, 
  N[rotateVector[{1, 0, 0}, 0, 0.02, 0]], Pi/100, Pi/100, Pi/100]]
```

Unfortunately, the performance drops (the scripts hangs) after drawing 5 values. I strongly suspect that the function `errorPropagation` is implemented improperly:

[image]

The values seem to be plausible, and the individual functions work well. But I am doing at least something wrong with the way I am using `NestList`. I would be greatful for any help to get my script plotting the curves as depicted by the figure shown further above.

***Update (2022-06-25):***
Following the straight-forward answer given by MarcoB I could generate the desired chart:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the ultimate purpose appears to be plotting, and since your code is already interspersed with calls to `N`, numerical results appear to be OK.

One problem is, however, that those calls to `N` are "too late", that is they appear *after* the expensive calculations have already been done symbolically. If you can get away with, it is always better for performance to start out with machine-precision results instead.

Below is a reformatted version of your code that easily handles **a few hundred points** essentially just by adding `N` *before* the expensive calculations rather than after.

I also got rid of the `Return` calls (you almost never need those: functions in MMA return the last value they calculate), and encapsulated each function body in a `Module` to localize variables. Note also that you don't need `MapThread` to do element-wise subtraction between two lists; you can just write `polar[[All, 2]] - polarErr[[All, 2]]`.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

qubitmatrixToCartesian[Mq_] := Module[{q1, q2, q3},
   q1 = Re[(Mq[[1, 2]] + Mq[[2, 1]])/2];
   q2 = Re[(Mq[[2, 1]] - Mq[[1, 2]])/(2*I)];
   q3 = Re[Mq[[1, 1]]];
   {q1, q2, q3}
  ]

rnSU2euler[vec_, rx_, ry_, rz_] := Module[{sphericalVec, \[Theta], \[Phi], sx, sy, sz, Mq, Un},
   sphericalVec = ToSphericalCoordinates[vec];
   \[Theta] = sphericalVec[[2]];
   \[Phi] = sphericalVec[[3]];
   sx = PauliMatrix[1];
   sy = PauliMatrix[2];
   sz = PauliMatrix[3];
   Mq = Sin[\[Theta]]*Cos[\[Phi]]*sx + Sin[\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Phi]]*sy + 
     Cos[\[Theta]]*sz;
   Un = {{Exp[-I*(rx + rz)/2]*Cos[ry/2], -Exp[-I*(rx - rz)/2]*
       Sin[ry/2]}, {Exp[I*(rx - rz)/2]*Sin[ry/2], 
      Exp[I*(rx + rz)/2]*Cos[ry/2]}};
   Un . Mq . ConjugateTranspose[Un]
 ]

rotateVector[vec_, rx_, ry_, rz_] := Module[{MqRotated},
   MqRotated = rnSU2euler[vec, rx, ry, rz];
   qubitmatrixToCartesian[MqRotated]
 ]

errorPropagation[n_, vec_, vecError_, rx_, ry_, rz_] := Module[{v, vErr, polar, polarErr},
   v = NestList[rotateVector[#, rx, ry, rz] &, N@vec, n];
   vErr = NestList[rotateVector[#, rx, ry, rz] &, N@vecError, n];
   polar = Map[ToSphericalCoordinates, v];
   polarErr = Map[ToSphericalCoordinates, vErr];
   polar[[All, 2]] - polarErr[[All, 2]]
 ]
   
ListPlot[
  errorPropagation[
    260, 
    {1, 0, 0}, 
    rotateVector[{1, 0, 0}, 0, 0.02, 0],
    Pi/100, Pi/100, Pi/100
  ]
]
```

[image: resulting plot with 260 points]

Comment: Thank you for this elegant answer and approach - just tried and it works great. One minor question: How do I need to ammend the code to plot both waves? Now we have the wave `polar[[All, 2]] - polarErr[[All, 2]]` and I would like to add the second wave obtained by `polar[[All, 3]] - polarErr[[All, 3]]`. Then I would have exactly the same as given by my first figure.

Comment: Forget my comment. I found it [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/226333) and it is easy and straight-forward as well.

Comment: @EldarSultanow Change the last line of `errorPropagation` to return `{polar[[All, 2]] - polarErr[[All, 2]], polar[[All, 3]] - polarErr[[All, 3]]}`.

Comment: Correct - already did and worked great (see my update in the OP). Again, thank you a lot!